# AssertThat with one parameter lib

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit

I was trying to execute a test from http://mapstruct.org/#get-started

And there they use the code

```
assertThat( carDto ).isNotNull();
```

Since in many tutorials they don't add the import clause for readability and i'm not master of testing tools, I added latest junit mvn dependency.

```
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And in Java, I added the import:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```

Eclipse is complaining there is only one alternative for assertThat which is

> assertThat(T, Matcher) in the type Assert is not applicable
>   for the arguments (CarDto)

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a method from a different lib I am not aware of? I searched on the internet and found something but i'm not sure it is widely adopted, I would like to have that in mind because we're going to use this in a real project.

PS: Also tried ***org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;*** but it yields the same error, the signature is the same for their lib.

Comment: For you information latest version of junit is 5.4, not 4.2.

Comment: `assertThat(..)` is from assertj which is not part of JUnit neither 4.X nor 5.X

Comment: @NoDataFound you see how much I know about testing hehe, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assertThat( carDto ).isNotNull();` looks like AssertJ, which is not distributed with JUnit. Have a look into this [Quick Start](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-quick-start.html).

Comment: Thank you Roland! This solved my problem. To those not much into testing like me, I also checked the [technology radar](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/languages-and-frameworks/assertj) to know the adoption level, and it seems it is a popular testing tool as of 2018 onwards =D